# Growl type notification timing issue

Tags: mootools, growl

So I'm using Mootools with the [JS_Growl](http://techtrouts.com/js_growl-mootools-based-javascript-growl-like-notifications/) plugin which is working  nicely, but I can’t get the notification to hang around long enough before the page submit to be useful.

Example [here…](http://beacons.hopewell.tv/growl)

Is there some kind of call back to the Growl plugin, so that when the notification is ‘done’, I can then do the redirect?

Alternatively perhaps there's some way of sensing when I've returned to the page after a successful submit to then raise the notification? You can see I'm submitting and item ID to a shopping cart page which then sends me back.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. My Javascript is very basic so visual code examples would be ideal.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the source code? This is a really really old plugin, hastily put together and patched so it works with MooTools 1.2. They don't even use Class. Hence, no Events mixin. No callbacks either.

```
/*
JS_Growl Mootools based notifier
Version 0.2
Developed and maintained by Carlos Ouro
http://techtrouts.com
*/
JS_Growl={
    //user callable properties / funcionalities
    notify:function(str){
        if(!this._v.initiated) this._a.init();
        var el=new Element('div',{
            'class':(Browser.Engine.name=='trident' && Browser.Engine.version<5)?'JS_Growl_notify_IE6':'JS_Growl_notify',
            'html':str
        });
        el.inject(this._o.container);
        var fx= new Fx.Morph(el, {
            'duration': 'short'
        });
        fx.set({
            'opacity':0,
            'display':'block'
        });
        fx.start({
            'opacity':[0,1]
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            fx.start({
                'opacity':[1,0]
            }).chain(function(){
                this.options.durtion='long';
                this.start({
                    'height':0,
                    'padding-top':0,
                    'padding-bottom':0,
                    'margin-top':0,
                    'margin-bottom':0
                }).chain(function(){
                    el.destroy();
                });
            });
        }, 2500);
    },

    //internal structure "à la fallforward ( http://fallforwardgame.com )"
    _v:{
        initiated:false
    },
    _a:{
        init:function(){
            JS_Growl._o.container=new Element('div', {'id':'JS_Growl_container'});
            JS_Growl._o.container.inject(document.body);
            JS_Growl._v.initiated=true;
            if(Browser.Engine.name=='trident' && Browser.Engine.version<5){                         
                //position "fixed"
                JS_Growl._o.container.setStyle({'position':'absolute'});
                JS_Growl._a.ie6_pos();
                window['addEvent']('scroll', JS_Growl._a.ie6_pos);
                window['addEvent']('resize', JS_Growl._a.ie6_pos);
            }
        },
        ie6_pos:function(){
            JS_Growl._o.container.setStyles({'top':Window.getScrollTop()+'px', 'left':Window.getWidth()+'px'});
        }
    },
    _o:{
        "container":null
    }
}
```

considering how small this is, refactoring it to do what you need should be a matter of minutes - 10 - 15 mins or so.

However, you may be able to fix this a lot easier - stop the submit event on the add to basket click. wait a while for the notification to be seen, say 2.5 seconds. resubmit or change `location.href`

here's a list of similar and more flexible plugins off the top of my head:

- http://mootools.net/forge/p/growler
- http://mootools.net/forge/p/notimoo

have fun.

Comment: Dimitar, 
thanks so much that was the clue I needed. I need to pause the submit event momentarily for the notification to be seen. I am however painfully unaware of how to do this. if you could bang together a quick example that would be great! I'll do some searches in the meantime. 

Also, yes I was aware this was an old plugin but still thought it usable. Let me get the submit event paused correctly, then I'll take a look at your growl suggestions and see if one of those might be more efficient to use. 

thanks again!